# How to Send Twitter Direct Message api

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

iam trying to build a twitter chat bot that will send dm to my followers, but how can i make it?

in [api docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/new-event) there is `event object` and `Message Data Object`, its different from other and i still dont get it how to use this.

for example, here is my code for sending a tweet

```php
$words = "my text";

    $connect = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, access_token, access_token_secret);
    $actions = $connect->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $words));
    $actions = json_encode($actions);
```

but when i tried the same parameter for sending dm, it said `Notice: Array to string conversion`
here is the code i tried

```php
$userIds = "12345678";
$words = "test Dm";

    $data = [
        'event' => [
            'type' => 'message_create',
            'message_create' => [
                'target' => [
                    'recipient_id' => $userIds
                ],
                'message_data' => [
                    'text' => $words
                ]]]];

$connect = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, access_token, access_token_secret);
$actions = $connect->post('direct_messages/events/new', array($data));
$actions = json_encode($actions);
```

and what should i do with that? to fix it. or should a add a function for that?